# Having a boot option in the grup menu to boot from usb

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, live-usb, usb-drive, live-environment

I want to boot from a usb plugged into the same place everytime (e.g tails, beta ubuntus, etc.).
I use triple boot and would like a extra option to click to boot from this specific usb.
I dont know how to do it properly and would like some help. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

### Boot USB from Internal Drive's GRUB Menu

Add the following menuentry to your internal drive's grub.cfg file:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu - flash drive" {
 search --set=root --fs-uuid xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux ($root)/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd ($root)/casper/initrd
}
```

Where xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx is the UUID of the USB's root partition.

The **preferred** method method to do this is to add the menuentry to /etc/grub.d/40_custom and then in Terminal run `sudo update-grub`